# How to tie the knot at the end of a hammock?

Tags: knots

My balcony is a bit small so I had to buy a smaller hammock stand and retie the hammock knot in order for it to fit in the smaller stand, it looked approximately like the image I appended below.

I think the knot was made approximately like this, but I know there are steps missing and I hope someone here might know the name of the knot and the details of tying it.

1. The hammock has a hem with small cutouts in it
2. Go through the hem with the cordage (end bit)
3. Drag out small loops in each cutout
4. Go through the loops with the cordage (end bit)
5. Magic
6. Beautiful hammock knot

I did not nail down step 5 very good so my knot is quite ugly.

Here is an image I found that looked similar to how it was...

[image: Knot]

Here is the prettier of the two knots I made...

[image: My good attempt]

Comment: Hi Emil, can you post a photo of your knot?

Comment: My knot is wrong though - I just wounded it up so it was similar and made a double knot. The one that was from the start had intricate turns and over under things inside the windings (lashings?). I think it also went back to the middle loop for some reason - maybe to help with the shape, mine is slacky on the sides but tight in the middle of the mat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the best books on knotwork ever written is the ***Ashley Book of Knots***, and the hammock knots are on page 588. Here is a [link to a pdf version of the book.](https://ia801904.us.archive.org/35/items/TheAshleyBookOfKnots/the%20ashley%20book%20of%20knots.pdf)  While this book tells you all you need to know, I am pretty sure it is not written in a way you can understand unless you work through a much bigger part of the book.

Not as professional but easier to understand are these two pages, text in Dutch: [Easier but less smooth.](https://www.knoopenzo.nl/hangmat/7.htm) [Harder but nicer.](https://www.knoopenzo.nl/hangmat/8.htm)

So far the link answers. Now the how-to without the pics:

- Undo the mass of string between the eye and the fabric of the hammock.
- Tie one temporary string or use a bit of sticky tape just below the eye (the bit which is neat in your second photo), and one just below where you want to stop the covering.
- Now take one long length of string, and tie a common wipping with it. ([See how it is done, in pictures and animated.](https://www.netknots.com/rope_knots/common-whipping)) [Video of the knot.](https://www.google.com/search?q=common%20whipping%20instructions&oq=common%20wipping%20&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0i13i512l2j0i22i30l5j0i15i22i30j0i22i30.5751j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#kpvalbx=_qBXDY5rSKoiB9u8P8pmHiAU_27)

This should help you with the bit you did not manage before.

It will help you if you keep a bit more space between the fabric and the eye of the hammock.

Comment: I think the dutch links you gave might be fancier than how the knot was from the store... but the common whipping looks very similar to how it was, I am not sure how to ensure the other end of the rope is secured as well though. Do I make both the eye and the "throat"/below eye with the same end of the rope ?

Comment: If you have enough length you can make both with the same end of the rope, but it is also an acceptable option to use two separate bits of rope. Or to use thinner string as they actually did in those Dutch links.

Comment: You can just wind the eye part and hide the ends in the neck part, make both as  wippings or, most difficult, make it one wipping.

Comment: I think doing it like in the dutch links would be too different, since I only have two ends not multiple. I am guessing maybe they would come from individual cutouts. But I think if I do common whipping with one end and then tie the other end together with it somehow, I might get a better knot.